# Constant treatment variable: Downwards bias of standard errors

Tags: standard-error, difference-in-difference, robust-standard-error

I'm reading a paper that claims

> The treatment variable is constant within each state. This causes the errors to be biased downwards.

However, the claim is not referenced, and I cant force my (weak) statistics intuition to make sense of this. The context is a US county-level regression where the treatment is on the US state level. The authors proceed claiming that clustering the standard errors at the state level will solve the issue. Could someone shed some light on these matters, or just cite some references for me to start treading in?

Comment: Is it possible to link the aforementioned paper?

Comment: @MatthewDrury unfortunately, no, otherwise I would've already.

Comment: So it goes.  I suppose it was still worth asking.

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/86w5m90m#page-8) paper, p. 952. Or at least a similar situation. The paper gives several references which might be of use, of which I like the [Betrand, Duflo, and Mullainathan](http://economics.mit.edu/files/750). I think the idea is that when you have variation in the DV at the individual level, but treatment is constant at the group level, you will have problems when you don't account for common group errors.